# 404 won't load images if in another directory

Tags: html, css, web, http-status-code-404

I have a custom 404 Error on my [website](http://ericmuir.tk) but when I get the error in a directory that is not the home one then it will not load any of the images on the page. I had a similar problem with loading my CSS scripts but put it in style tags but that is another topic.

So my question is, is there anyway to let the 404 error load images in the parent directory if it is needed else would there be any way to allow it to load them no matter what directory it is 'summoned' in.

Sitemap [here](http://ericmuir.tk/sitemap.xml)

Comment: that doesn't work for me for some reason, I have no idea why, just brings up the picture icon and the name of the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of **Absolute Url** is your solution.

Suppose you have uploaded your 404 error image in a directory

```
example.com
 |-images
  |-error.jpg
```

In error.php file link image as

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/error.jpg">
```

Now you can use/access from anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason, thanks anyway

Comment: @ericmuir123 can you show the directory tree. your website doesn't load from my place.

Comment: @SUMANKC Yeah I just posted it know, thanks for your interest in it

Comment: I had the same problem and realized that I was lacking a `/`. If you have the same problem than I do, you probably do `images/error.jpg` instead of `/images/error.jpg`

Comment: /images/error.jpg doesn't work for me for some strange reason, might this be a htaccess setting?

Comment: I can't use an absolute URL because it should be different on the staging server from the production server, and I need to be able to push from stage to prod without making changes. And for some reason a relative url (even "/images/image.png") only works at the root. If I'm several pages down and you look at img props it shows "<current file path>/images/image.png". I'm going to have to host the images elsewhere, I think.